# ¿Cómo guardar un archivo cargado a mi formulario?

Tags: django

He creado un formulario para registrar datos y guardarlos en una base de datos.

Entre los datos tengo diversos tipos de archivos, pero cuando cargo el archivo y doy a guardar me carga todos los datos a mi BD menos el archivo incluido.

Este seria parte del codigo de mi formulario:

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Django | Formulario {% endblock %}

{% block Contenido %}
<body style="background-color:rgb(212, 224, 224);">
  </body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row main">
                <div class="main-login main-center">
          {% if object %}
            <form class="" method="post" action="{{ request.path }}">
          {% else %}
            <form class="" method="post" action="{{ request.path }}">
          {% endif %}
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="nombre" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Nombre</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-users fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.nombre }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="apellidos" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Apellidos</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.apellidos }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="ci" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Cedula de identidad</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.ci }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="cargo" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Cargo actual</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.cargo }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Correo Electronico</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.email}}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="telefono" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Telefono</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.telefono }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="documento" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Archivo</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                    {{ form.documento }}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                  <input class="{% if object %}btn btn-success {% else %} btn btn-primary {% endif %} btn-lg btn-block login-button" type="submit" name="Registrar" value="{% if object %} Editar {% else %} Registrar {% endif %}">
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <hr />
</div>

{% endblock Contenido %}

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: creo que te falta solo la siguiente linea `<form enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: necesitaríamos ver el controlador, esto es, allá donde estás guardando la información

Comment: La informacion se esta guardando en postgres

Comment: por favor agrega el cambio que te envie y tambien te invito a hacer el [tour]

Answer (score 0):

Los archivos no debes guardarlos en la base de datos, lo que guardas en la base de datos en la referencia al archivo que se guarda en los "media" de tu aplicación.

Tienes correctamente seteada la configuración de los Media Files?

Por otro lado porque haces el formulario manualmente? deberías crear un form en el archivo forms.py e implementarlo dinámicamente en el template.

Saludos!

Comment: este es mi form.py:

Comment: No se ve, deberías editar tu post y poner el model, la vista y el forms!

Answer (score 0):

Buenas ya lo resolvi modificando el model.py:
from django.db import models

class Empleados(models.Model):

```
nombre = models.CharField(max_length=15)
apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=15)
ci = models.IntegerField()
cargo = models.CharField(max_length=15)
creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
email = models.EmailField()
telefono = models.CharField(max_length=12)
documento = models.FileField(
upload_to="archivo/",
null=True,
blank=True
)

def __str__(self):
    return '%s'% (self.nombre)
```

class ActualizacionEmpleado(models.Model):
    empleado = models.OneToOneField('Empleados', null = False, blank = False, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    fecha_actualizacion = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

```
def __str__(self):
    return '%s'% (self.nombre)
```

Pero ahora cuando consulto un dato no me muestra la fecha de actualizacion, y no se me ocurre que hacer para que me lo muestre. este es mi form.
from django import forms
from django.contrib.admin import widgets
from datos.models import Empleados, ActualizacionEmpleado
from django.forms import ModelForm

class EmpleadoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Empleados

```
    fields = [
        'nombre',
        'apellidos',
        'ci',
        'cargo',
        'email',
        'telefono',
        'documento',

    ]
    widgets = {
        'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Introduzca nombre'}),
        'apellidos': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Introduzca apellidos'}),
        'ci': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control','type':'number','placeholder':'Introduzca ci'}),
        'cargo': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Introduzca cargo'}),
        'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Introduzca email'}),
        'telefono': forms.TextInput(attrs = {'class':'form-control','placeholder':'Introduzca solo numero de telefono'}),
    }
```

ademas mi template detalle.html:
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block Contenido %}

Registro ID #:

{{ object.id }}

Nombre:

{{ object.nombre }}

Apellidos:

{{ object.apellidos }}

Cedula de identidad:

{{ object.ci }}

Fecha de ingreso:

{{ object.creado }}

Email:

{{ object.email }}

Telefono:

{{ object.telefono }}

Documento:

{{ object.documento }}

Ultima actualizacion:

{{ object.fecha_actualizacion }}

{% endblock %}
que me falta o que estoy haciendo mal, agradezco la ayuda, gracias

Answer (score 0):

Al llamar un formulario en la vista necesitas recibir los archivos del request:

```
form = MI_FORMULARIO(
    request.POST or None, request.FILES or None
)
```